# Optimal strategy for this probability problem?

Tags: probability

You know that a bomb will hit you in exactly 10 minutes. There are two bomb shelters, A and B. You want to optimize your chance of survival.

You are now at bomb shelter A with 50% survival chance.
You can run to bomb shelter B with 100% survival chance. You don't know exactly how far away B is, but you guess it is between 1 and 20 minutes. You can find out how far exactly by making a 4-minute phone call, from a landline phone in shelter A.
If the bomb hits while you're in the open field, you're dead.

What should you do?

Comment: Nice problem. Where does it come from? Do you know that the shelter B is less than 7 minutes far?

Comment: Start running, make the phone call meanwhile (thank god for cell phones). If it says bombshelter $B$ is more than 10 minutes away, turn around for bombshelter $A$ and hope for the best.

Comment: I would optimize the chance of the 'right' outcome by going on my knees and pray for it. In my view there is no better way to use your time.

Comment: @BeniBogosel: I invented this particular problem, but I guess there must be a class of problems like it. Let's say you're not entirely sure if shelter B is less than 7 minutes far, it's just a guess.

Comment: @Nameless: No cellphones! Only a landline phone at shelter A :)

Comment: It would be irrational to head towards the other shelter without calling first if you don't even know if it's less than $10$ minutes away.

Comment: But if it's less than 10 minutes you can make it there for sure. You need to assign some kind of probability to it being within a given distance or something like that. I'm not sure specifically how you should do this.

Comment: Ok, I adapted the numbers slightly.

Comment: You might say that the probability is equal of $B$ being any amount of time in the specified range away.

Answer (score 1):

We need to assign a probability distribution to $AB$ before we can answer this. If we assume a uniform distribution on $[1,20]$, then we can compute survival probabilities for the various options:

- Cower in shelter $A$. Survival probability: $\frac12$
- Run to shelter $B$. Survival probability: $\frac9{19}$
- Make that phone call. Survival probability: $\frac5{19} + \frac12 \times \frac{14}{19}$

So the third option is the clear winner.